# Extracting the integers from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list where the elements are Reals and Integers. How can I extract the Integer? For example, if I have `{1, 2, 3.4, 9.9}`, how can I get `{1, 2}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this command

```
Cases[list, _Integer]
```

Comment: Thanks.. it runs. But when i erase the `{1}` at the end of the command, it also runs. What is the meaning of `{1}`?

Comment: To just check on the first level of the list. Actually by default it takes {1} so I better remove it too!

Answer (score 5):

Well since we're having fun, I'll like to join the party:

```
lst = {3, 5.6, 8.19, 2, 5.6, 4, 3, 8.5, 4.137, 7., 1.165}

DeleteCases[lst, _Real]
```

OR

```
lst /. x_Real -> Sequence[]
```

OR

```
Select[lst, Head[#] == Integer &]
```

All give:

```
{3, 2, 4, 3}
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thanks, you got my vote too :)

Comment: I added a couple more to my answer.  I hope you enjoy them.

Comment: Why not `Select[lst, IntegerQ]`?

Comment: @J.M., that too. Isn't `Head[#]==Integer&` what MMA is doing under the hood when you use `IntegerQ`?

Comment: I suppose, but I would think `IntegerQ` is idiomatic, while the actual head test is more literal. :)

Comment: @J.M., I agree.

Comment: @J.M. that's not nearly enough fun; be more creative! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's a terse method using `Pick`:

```
lst = {3, 5.6, 8.19, 2, 5.6, 4, 3, 8.5, 4.137, 7., 1.165}

Pick[#,#-#,0]& @ lst
```

> ```
> {3, 2, 4, 3}
> ```

More fun:

```
Replace[lst, _Real|x_ :> x, 1]
```

> ```
> {3, 2, 4, 3}
> ```

Only for positive values:

```
Log@lst ~Level~ {2}
```

> ```
> {3, 2, 4, 3}
> ```

Comment: Oh wow, that last one using `Log` is clever, wish I could Upvote again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one, for fun:

```
lst = {3, 5.6, 8.19, 2, 5.6, 4, 3, 8.5, 4.137, 7., 1.165};
Pick[lst, Mod[lst, 1], 0]
(* {3, 2, 4, 3} *)
```

Comment: ...or `SawtoothWave[lst]`.

Comment: .. or `Gamma[lst] - (lst - 1)!` :D

Answer (score 0):

if order does not matter:

```
Attributes[f] = {Orderless};
f[x__Integer, __] := {x}
f @@ {3, 5.6, 8.19, 2, 5.6, 4, 3, 8.5, 4.137, 7., 1.165}

(* {2, 3, 3, 4} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select[lst, Round[#] == #&];
Select[lst, # == Round[#]&];
```